# MVC Razor HTML helpers not rendered when $(document).ready(

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, document-ready

I just noticed that my MVC Razor HTML helpers arent rendered (in DOM) when my javascript is calling $(document).ready(function....
So when I put code that is dependent on DOM objects in the document ready, it doesnt find the DOM objects.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio,select').change(function () {
        DO STUFF...
```

HTML helpers

```
@Html.RadioButtonList(m => m.ItemType, new SelectList(Model.ItemTypes, "Name", "Name")
```

another

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.ApartmentFloor, new SelectList(Model.ApartmentFloors, "Id", "Floor"), new { @id = "floorsSelect", @class = "exists" })
```

Normally, the radiobuttons and the dropdowns should get a .change function, but since they arent rendered yet when the .change is added, they dont get that function.

Is there a way to get "on html helpers ready" instead of "on document ready"?

**Edit**:

People have pointed out that HTML helpers run on the server, before the client starts to render, thus should be finished before as well. This doesn't seem to be the case, since, when I debug the JS "on document ready", the HTML helpers objects aren't rendered yet but the rest of the page is.

So the question remains, is there a way to add a "on load" function the HTML helper object, or to add a "change" function directly from the cshtml file with razor syntax?

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense, since helpers are executed on the server (**before** response is sent to the client and javascript can run)

Comment: ..unless it is an ajax loaded partial view, and the script is already in page, is it the case?

Comment: Hm, what you say sounds logical. But still, I've tried searching for a DOM object when I'm in the doucment.ready and it's not found. So for some reason the DOM isnt completely rendered yet...

Comment: As far as I know its not an Ajax loaded partial view. The helpers are in a cshtml file, which is then directly called upon by its url.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with my RadioButtonList? Im using this one: http://pastebin.com/hTzY9vP5

Comment: We do stuff with MVC Razor Helpers all the time including drop down lists and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I never posted the solution to my problem.
Even though people pointed out that HTML helpers should be rendered before document ready, this didnt seem to be the case for me.
So what I did was to add the event handler directly on the HTML helper instead:

`@Html.RadioButtonList(m => m.MyObject, new SelectList(Model.MyObjects, "Name", "Name"), "inputChangeHandler($(this));")`

Works great =)

Comment: Also, I noticed that the position of the JS include in the cshtml files changed the behavior of the page. If I put the document ready JS above the HTML helpers, the HTML helpers weren't rendered upon doc ready. But if I put the JS below, they were rendered... Weird, I thought it didn't matter if you put the JS in the top or bottom of a file..

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the event like this,

```
      $('input:radio,select').on("change" ,function () { }) ;
```

Hope this shall help.